# Проблема с тенями

Tags: unity3d

Почему, когда я отдаляю камеру, у меня на мобиле, пропадают тени?
`Shadow Distance` не помогает.

Главное, работает на компе в самой юнити. а после компила, теней нет.
Но как только я, приближаю впритык камеру (ну почти впритык), компилю, тень есть.

И как с этим бороться?
Кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой, что-то ничего не могу найти.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зря задал вопрос, настройки не верные выставил для девайсов, нужно было `Quality -> Medium` выбирать, а я `Ultra` ставил, не видел, что там галочки не соответствуют.

Все норм работает теперь.